# Storing Tags in Firebase from a POST request for a different collection in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I have two collections, `posts` and `tags`. `posts` contains a `postId` and other metadata, including `tags`. This is what a `post` would look like:

```
{
    "tags": [
        "tag1",
        "tag2",
        ...
    ],
    "message": "test message"
    ...
}
```

This returns the post above, with a `postId`.

Using Axios, I receive this data in my function. I want to take each tag, put them in the `tags` collection along with the `postId` associated with it.

An example of the `tags` collection:

```
tags: {
    tag1: {
        "postId1",
        "postId2"
    },
    tag2: {
         "postId1",
         "postId3"
    }
}
```

I'm stuck adding the tags to its own collection in Firebase, and I've tried using `forEach` tag and updating the `tags` collection one by one, but that hasn't been working for me.

The code I currently have:

```
  db.collection("posts")
    .add(oneNewPost)
    .then((doc) => {
      // add the post body to the "posts" collection
      const resPost = oneNewPost;
      resPost.postId = doc.id;
      res.json(resPost);
    })
    .then(() => {
      // DOESNT WORK HERE --> overwrites changes in firebase "tags" collection
       let batch = db.batch();
      resPost.tags.forEach((doc) => {
        const docRef = db.collection("tags").doc(doc);
        batch.update(docRef, { postId: resPost.postId }, { merge: true });
      });
      batch.commit().then(() => {
        return res.json({...resPost});
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).json({ error: "something went wrong" });
      console.error(err);
    });
```

Please let me know if anything is unclear!

Comment: "...but that hasn't been working for me..." - Can you please describe the error or buggy behavior you are having in detail. Also in the code snippet you posted, I can't seem to find the code you're using to update the tag collection, please include that.

Comment: I edited the code snippet with the code I've tried. It adds to the "tags" collection with the tag as the id, and the postId, but it overwrites it if I run the POST request again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work using the following code:

```
 .then((resPost) => {
      // add postId's to tag collection here
      let batch = db.batch();
      resPost.tags.forEach((doc) => {
        const docRef = db.doc(`/tags/${doc}`);
        batch.update(
          docRef,
          { postId: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(resPost.postId) },
          { merge: true }
        );
      });
      batch
        .commit()
        .then(() => {
          return res.json({ ...resPost });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.error(err);
          return res.status(500).json({ error: err.code });
        });
    })
```

Basically, you need to do a batch update, but also for a specific `FieldlValue` for each `postId`.